# Configure server so PDF downloads do not open in Browsers

Tags: pdf, mime-types, content-type

I am working on a public-facing application that presents links to fillable PDF forms for download.

Browser's built-in PDF renderers are fine for brochures and static text, but they really can't cope with fillable forms very well: a lot of times a message is displayed telling the user to open in a dedicated PDF viewer like Adobe Reader, and the general public calling our tech support line every times this happens is unsustainable.

What is the best way to configure our server so the browser won't even try to open these PDFs (some way to specifying 'this PDF is beyond your capabilities'), and optimally, the downloaded file opens directly in a user-selectable client?

Ideally, if the user has Adobe Reader installed, the first time they visit our site and download a fillable form, they are prompted to choose an application: hopefully the list of choices highlights Adobe Reader or a similarily capable client... and after they configure their browser to "open with..." Adobe Reader one time, from that point on, links to PDFs from our site should trigger the file opening in Adobe Reader automatically without additional interaction on the part of the user (or perhaps just "Open With.." with Adobe Reader preselected)

Using the "download" attribute on the  element is being considered, but is there a way to configure the Content-Type (mime-type) differently for "fillable" PDFs that Browsers can't render fully, that is known to be "best"?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the PDFs in a folder on the server and then create an .htaccess file in the same folder. The .htaccess file should set the content-disposition to "attachment". This will force the browser to download the file.

```
Header set Content-Disposition "attachment"
```

Comment: I think some of the PDFs are dynamically generated but I will try to see about getting the server configured with the Content Disposition as "attachment" in the response header, thanks!